# Adapting a ConvexHull fonction to a ConcaveHull one

Tags: postgis, convex-hull, concave-hull

I have a database with over 150 000 points in a EPSG 2950 projection. As I wanted to cluster those points in polygons, I used a ConvexHull fonction. The goal was to create clusters where I would find AT LEAST 5 points at a MAX DISTANCE of 75 meters from one to another.

The fonction I used was the following:

```
Select *
INTO new_table
 FROM (Select ST_ConvexHull
    (unnest
     (ST_ClusterWithin(geom, 75)))
      AS geom from my_table) sq
Where ST_NPoints(geom) >= 5
```

The fonction worked really well but now I would like to try to have clusters where the perimeter is a bit more representative of the points inside (The convexHull can leave big gaps where there is no points).

To do so I tried replacing the ConvexHull fonction for a ConcaveHull one:

```
Select *
INTO new_table
 FROM (Select ST_ConcaveHull
    (ST_Collect(unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(geom, 75), 0.70)))
      AS geom my_table) sq 
Where ST_NPoints(geom) >= 5
```

This specific function returned the following error...

> ERROR:  the function unnest(geometry[], numeric) doesn't exist
>   LINE 4:     (ST_Collect(unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(geom, 75), 0.70)))

I have tried some variants (as using the ConcaveHull function before the FROM clause) but the closest I got was getting 1 ConcaveHull over ALL my points and therefore ignoring the constraint of having AT LEAST 5 points at a MAX DISTANCE of 75 m.

Any ideas to solve my problem?

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: I have edited the question with the error.

Comment: Try to create triangles from the points (ST_DelaunayTriangles) and unite (ST_Union) along the longest side of the triangles.

Comment: There you go - mismatched parentheses.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I tried to correct the said error and can't find the correct way to do so